# Can't install Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, boot, 13.04, usb

I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 on a Dell Mini 10 that is currently running Qimo. I want to replace the old operating system entirely. When I turn on the computer and boot from the USB stick it brings up a black screen that says:

Boot:

I have no idea where to go from here. I created the bootable USB stick using Universal USB installer. I've used the same process for installing Ubuntu on other machines in the past have never had this issue. Thanks in advance for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try these things :

1 . Check if the ISO image your copied over to flash-drive is NOT corrupted.

[Hint : You could get the MD5 Hash code from the download page of Ubuntu. And then you have to check if that matches with your downloaded ISO. You have to calculate Your ISO's hash for that. You can do that by:

$ md5sum .iso

If both codes are matching, your ISO is OK. There can be a problem with your flash drive, or the copy of ISO on it.
Then,

2 . Either try using another flash-drive, or use another program to make your USB-stick bootable.

[You can use `dd' (Search for it)]